# use existing SSRS Reports in a Visual C# app using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, reportviewer

I have several reports built inside a project named SSRS and would like access to those reports inside a different Visual C# project (VS 2010).  What would the proper way to handle this be?

My thoughts were to try to add the SSRS project to the solution but I cannot seem to find a way to reference it in the C# WinForm project.  Maybe I am going about this wrong.  This is the first time I have ever built reports and tried to use them in an application.

End result will be using a reportViewer control docked in its own windows form for display of the report.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  I have looked around and most the info points to older versions of VS and/or SQL Server.  BTW I used SQL Server 2012 SQL Server Data Tools to create the reports.

Comment: Do you need the reports in your project? If they are existing reports you can configure the Report Viewer control to point to the report server where the reports are held. Have you read this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252104.aspx

Comment: Yes I need them in my project.  I do not wish to run them remotely either.  I have already created the reports and data sources inside the SSRS proj.  I mostly would like to have access to them from the report viewer if I add the ssrs proj to the main solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish this I needed to recreate the reports as .rdlc files inside the project and created a datasource inside the app to use.